# how to display find() result of mongodb embedded document in php

Tags: php, mongodb

```
{
   "_id": NumberInt(13),
   "name": "vishal",

   "friends": [
     {
       "name1": "vini",
       "count": NumberInt(213) 
   },
   {
       "name1": "sumesh",
       "count": NumberInt(47) 
   }],
   "blog": NumberInt(5) 
}
```

i need to display the name,name1 of all doc & blog in php , using `foreach()` i got the parent document "name" but dint get name1& blog ?

Comment: you can try unwind in aggregation pipeline

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: Can you include the PHP code you are using to find and iterate? From the current description it's not clear why the embedded document fields aren't being included, but the problem is likely in how you are iterating the results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try unwind in aggregation pipeline

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind:"$friends"}])
```

Hope it will help